# Hiding Storyblok API-Key

Tags: next.js, storyblok

I'm using Next.js with Storyblok and recently made use of the [react-next-boilerplate](https://github.com/storyblok/react-next-boilerplate/).

I noticed that they put the preview token in the `_app.js`, so essentially publish it:

```js
storyblokInit({
  accessToken: "your-preview-token",
  use: [apiPlugin],
  components,
});
```

If I use an environment variable instead, which isn't available on the client, I get the error

> You need to provide an access token to interact with Storyblok API

in the client.  That's because (I think) my components use `StoryblokComponent`, which makes use of the global Storyblok state.  So I wonder:

- Should I ignore this error, as I don't plan to interact with the Storyblok API other than using it for component rendering (all the data comes from the server, as far as I understand the concept of static site generation), and component rendering seems to be still working?
- Should I just publish the preview token?
- Should I create two tokens, one for the server and one for the client?
- Setting the token to `process.env.STORYBLOK_API_KEY || "NULL"` (where `"NULL"` can be anything except the empty string) also works (no more errors) but seems like a weird solution.

I don't really understand why they combine these two things, component rendering and data fetching, in the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `.env.local` file and populate it with:

```
STORYBLOK_API_KEY=your-preview-token
```

To use the environment variable inside `_app.js` you have to pass it to `next.config.js` like this:

```
    module.exports = {
      env: {
        STORYBLOK_API_KEY: process.env.STORYBLOK_API_KEY,
      }
    }
```

Source: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: I did this and it works, but is there a way to get rid of the "You need to provide an access token to interact with Storyblok API." message in the client console.

Comment: To add to this, if you don't want to use `next.config.js`, and just want to use an `.env` you can just [prefix your env variables with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser) so the values are accessible on the client

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Auth section](https://www.storyblok.com/docs/api/content-delivery/v2#topics/authentication) in the API documentation clarifies things

> Public and Preview tokens are read only and do not allow you or others to write or delete entries in your space. The public token can be published. All tokens can be revoked at any point in time. You can also create multiple tokens of the same type to grant access for specific use-cases.

If you think about it, the Storyblok client is intended to be able to work in frontend frameworks, so it makes sense that you can include these read-only access tokens in the client bundle (i.e., what next is doing)

##### To answer the specific questions:

###### *Should I ignore this error, as I don't plan to interact with the Storyblok API other than using it for component rendering?*

[As the docs point out](https://github.com/storyblok/storyblok-js-client#class-storyblok), `accessToken` is optional if you don't plan to use it to read content from the client.

###### *Should I create two tokens, one for the server and one for the client?*

In your particular use-case, you're using next to statically build your app. If the static build (i.e., a server) is what's retrieving content, you could just have the one accessToken in your env, and exclude it from the client.

###### Should I just publish the preview token?

It's perfectly fine to do so as the docs point to above, but per the previous question, it's perfectly reasonable to just have it on the server as long as the sb client doesn't yell at you once the app is statically built

###### *Setting the token to process.env.STORYBLOK_API_KEY || "NULL" (where "NULL" can be anything except the empty string) also works (no more errors) but seems like a weird solution.*

Yeah, this is because you're defining the `accessToken` property on the sb client options, but the value is empty. If you don't include the property, the client won't throw an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment.  Yes, that makes sense and that's also what I encountered with other CMSs as the default. I'm not using Storyblok anymore, but hopefully somebody who still does will find the answer helpful!